# MySQL Proxy Query Rewriting

Tags: mysql, lua, mysql-proxy

I would like to change all `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries with `SELECT COUNT(1)` (for this use case).

I have the following lua script, but it does not work somehow:

```
function read_query( packet )
   if string.byte(packet) == proxy.COM_QUERY then
     local query = string.sub(packet, 2)
     local replacing = false
     if string.match(string.upper(query), 'COUNT(*)') then
         query = string.gsub(query,'COUNT(*)', 'COUNT(1)')
         replacing = true
     end
     if (replacing) then
         proxy.queries:append(1, string.char(proxy.COM_QUERY) .. query )
         return proxy.PROXY_SEND_QUERY
     end
   end
 end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for the string "COUNT(*)" remember the second parameter is a pattern and not a simple string, you could escape the string using

**Inhibit Regular Expression magic characters ^$()%.[]*+-?)**

Prefix every non-alphanumeric character (%W) with a % escape character,where %% is the % escape, and %1 is original character

```
function strPlainText(strText)
    return strText:gsub("(%W)","%%%1")
end
```

so

```
if string.match(string.upper(query), strPlainText('COUNT(*)')) then
```

Comment: Sorry, it did not work for me. But this did:   if string.lower(query) == 'select count(*) from mysql.user'  then

Comment: Although that does not answer my original use case